# Azure Databricks secret keys name into jdbc property

Tags: python, databricks, secret-key

I just have create a Azure Key vault backed secret scope.
My following secret names(stored as secrets in Key Vault) to connect to Azure SQL Database:

1. jdbcusername
2. jdbcpassword

After that i have created secret scope in databricks. the name of this secret scope  is secretscopeadbr

In my notebook i have the following code:
This code has the JDBC connection based my Azure SQL database and write data from a dataframe to a single table in my azure sql database.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pandas as pd

#Read the parquet file#
outerjoindfparquet = spark.read.format('parquet').load('dbfs:/newjouterjoindfparquet.parquet')
display (outerjoindfparquet)

#Write Parquet file to  Azure SQL Database#
mountdatabricksjdbcHostname = "sql-ja-dev.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = "1433"
jdbcDatabase = "sqldb-ja-dev"
properties = {
        "user": "jdbcusername",
        "password": "jdbcpassword"
    }
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(mountdatabricksjdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
filedf = sqlContext.read.parquet("dbfs:/newjouterjoindfparquet.parquet", header=True)

filedf1 = DataFrameWriter(filedf)
filedf1.jdbc(url=url, table="Fact_SalesOrder", mode="overwrite", properties=properties)
```

The issue:
The inserted secret values in the properties does not recognized.

Error message:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'jdbcUsername'

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have left jdbcusername and jdbcpassword within quotes.

Try this.

```
properties = {
        "user": jdbcusername,
        "password": jdbcpassword
    }
```

Comment: No unfortunatly is not working

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'jdbcUsername'

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix:

i added two new variables which called JdbcUserName and JdbcPassword. This pointed to the dbutils.secrets.get

```
JdbcUserName= dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "myscope", key = "sqljadevadminloginname")
JdbcPassword= dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "myscope", key = "sqljadevpassword")
properties = {
        "user": JdbcUserName,
        "password": JdbcPassword
    }
```